# Dell inspiron 14R has no network after kubuntu installation

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dell

I've just installd the LTS version of Kubuntu, and i can't connect to any network, wired OR wireless..
Most of the answers i've seen here assumed there's only a problem with the wireless, so i'm kinda stuck. i've tried installing "compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p.tar.bz2" and following the steps to install it but the problem persists,
I've got a dell inspiron 14R 5420, dual boot with win7, in which everything works fine.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are your drivers for the network cards loading? A quick check might be to mouse over your network  notification area or try to manually connect to a network (I'm not terribly familiar with KDE). Running *lspci -vv* might net you some information about the cards and what driver they are using , if they are using one.

Comment: No, the network cards aren't loading.